# Losing session variables after redirecting from the page

Tags: asp.net

Please Help me, I am storing some session variables but after redirecting to another page in different server I am not able to retrieve my session variables. Can anybody tell me hw can I get the session variables back. I am using javasript to redirect in my aspx page

```
    function check_empty()
    {
      document.merForm.action="https://3dsecure.payseal.com/MultiMPI/from_icici_merchant.jsp";
      document.merForm.submit();
    }
```

Comment: How are you storing session variables? are you trying to use session variable in another web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use the default Session state variables across multi servers. It is possible using different modes, however. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx